# disable mic in android

Tags: android

Is there any way i could disable(not mute) the mic through programming. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there is no way to disable completely the microphone. The only option you have is to mute it using the AudioManager.

[Audio Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode%28int%29)